# Unknown black component on PCB

Tags: pcb

This black component becomes very warm and I have a feeling it is broken since it becomes very hot compared to the other two similar ones.

Can't find any part number or anything.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a ferrite core, possibly a balun. What is the circuit board from?

Comment: Its a sinusodial transmitter 200z03300a

Comment: You cannot assume that if something is warm, it is broken. This is wrong thinking usually.

Comment: Balun or choke of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSoUaD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[The patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/27/16/1c/891492f120749f/EP2545758B1.pdf)

The purpose of this ferrite Balun here is to attenuate unwanted noise in RF band on the DC line used by RF amplifiers.

Heat is an indication of high RF CM noise either radiated or conduction on DC power line from card edge due to unbalanced , unshielded DC external wires acting as antenna.

There may be a fault in the load causing this to heat up.

Comment: wow, what amount of energy must that antenna be picking up to heat up such a massive amount of metal

Comment: very warm for this size might be 1/4W @MarcusMüller   is that massive?

Comment: hm, true, I simply might have different understanding of "very warm" than OP.

Comment: whereas a 1/4W body size dissipating 1/4 would be > 125'C and vaporize moisture instantly and cause loss of permeability and drop in XL(f) with thermal runaway in ferrite

Comment: by the way, are you sure about the intended usage? This device looks like something that powers cables you can bury with AC so your autonomous lawn mover gets an invisible cage :)

Comment: judging by nearby components and PCB edge pads ,it appears to be connected to a DC-DC converter bus.

Comment: very warm meaning it burns to the touch, and discoloration on the backside(brownish).
Ive checked a troubleshooting guide for this device and it said it said that if it blinks yellow then its problem with the transmitter. 
Can the transmitter be causeing that all the ampage seems to be over the component?
Ive done measurements on the transformer and it gives 30v as it says but when i measure on the pcb connectors there is a big voltage drop(current being limited).
Its very hard to troubleshoot anything since i cant find a schematic and im kinda new with all this.

Comment: T>60'C burns to touch  . epoxy discoloration > 125'C

Comment: Looking at what it's glued to, the heat may come from Q9 rather than RF. Also, that looks like hot melt adhesive, which is still in the area, so possibly not all that hot.

Comment: I suspect DC saturation of ferrite has created a lot of heat from servo motor direction and loss in the choke.  It's hard to read the patents to find a clue on fault isolation https://patents.google.com/?assignee=Fabrizio+Bernini